# CSS Overflow Hidden Workaround?

Tags: css, overflow, css-float

Wondering if anyone has a work around for this issue.

I've got a markup like this:

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner">
content here
</div>
</div>
```

now my inner div isnt always extending as far as I would like it.

[image]

Overflow: hidden; works wonders, but in this case I have some elements that overlap the edge so I cant use that. Float:left; is good but I dont want to specify a width every time.

Ideally I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: could you just use `left: 0px` in your CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to [clearing floats](http://work.arounds.org/clearing-floats/), since you seem to lack CSS in the example then you'd just use a clearfix:

```
#outer:after {
    content:"";
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}

#outer { zoom:1; }
```

If not, please include the full HTML/CSS in a jsfiddle or link to the real thing.